# Auto update electron The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: electron, auto-update

I've copied both js files from electron auto-updater into my app

auto-updater-win.js

```
'use strict'

const {app} = require('electron')
const {EventEmitter} = require('events')
const squirrelUpdate = require('./squirrel-update-win')

class AutoUpdater extends EventEmitter {
  quitAndInstall () {
    if (!this.updateAvailable) {
      return this.emitError('No update available, can\'t quit and install')
    }
    squirrelUpdate.processStart()
    app.quit()
  }

  getFeedURL () {
    return this.updateURL
  }

  setFeedURL (updateURL, headers) {
    this.updateURL = updateURL
  }

  checkForUpdates () {

    console.log("checkForUpdates/zzzzz");
    if (!this.updateURL) {
      return this.emitError('Update URL is not set')
    }
    if (!squirrelUpdate.supported()) {
      return this.emitError('Can not find Squirrel')
    }
    this.emit('checking-for-update')
    squirrelUpdate.download(this.updateURL, (error, update) => {
        console.log("squirrelUpdate.download");

      if (error != null) {
        return this.emitError(error)
      }
      if (update == null) {
        return this.emit('update-not-available')
      }
      this.updateAvailable = true
      this.emit('update-available')
      squirrelUpdate.update(this.updateURL, (error) => {
        if (error != null) {
          return this.emitError(error)
        }
        const {releaseNotes, version} = update
        // Date is not available on Windows, so fake it.
        const date = new Date()
        this.emit('update-downloaded', {}, releaseNotes, version, date, this.updateURL, () => {
          this.quitAndInstall()
        })
      })
    })
  }

  // Private: Emit both error object and message, this is to keep compatibility
  // with Old APIs.
  emitError (message) {
    this.emit('error', new Error(message), message)
  }
}

module.exports = new AutoUpdater()
```

and squirrel-update-win.js

In renderer.js I have set up the auto-updater to use the local files not those from electron

const autoUpdater = require('./auto-updater-win');

checkForUpdates gets fired,

the url looks like http://test.com:3000/updates/latest?v=1.0.4

it can be accesed from the browser and returns the url to the zip file of the new version in json

```
 this.emit('checking-for-update')
 squirrelUpdate.download(this.updateURL, (error, update) => {
 console.log("squirrelUpdate.download");
```

...
also gets called from auto-updater-win.js

then from squirrel-update-win.js
when

// Download the releases specified by the URL and write new results to stdout.

```
exports.download = function (updateURL, callback) {
  console.log(updateURL);
  return spawnUpdate(['--download', updateURL], false, function (error, stdout) {...}
```

is hit
it gives me this error

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Any Ideea how to solve it? Please I need some help :)

Many thanks.

Comment: If you have access to a server, try to log all incoming requests, because there might be just wrong URL. Also, try to removing version argument from URL.

Comment: Ok tried that and now the app comunicates with the server, but now I have this error One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Invalid release entry: {"url":"http://localhost:3000/releases/wind/1.0.4/MyApp.zip"}

Comment: Here it says something like this : The way Squirrel.Mac works is by checking a given API endpoint to see if there is a new version of the app. If there is no new version, the endpoint should return HTTP 204. If there is a new version, however, it will expect a HTTP 200 JSON-formatted response, containing a url to a .zip file:  {
  "url": "http://Localhost/path/to/zip/MyApp.zip"
}

Comment: I did somethig wrong here?

Comment: Please, check [this guide](https://medium.com/@svilen/auto-updating-apps-for-windows-and-osx-using-electron-the-complete-guide-4aa7a50b904c#.ffcjivx99).

Comment: Yes and this is the json from server in the example res.json({
      url: `${getBaseUrl()}/releases/darwin/${latest}/MyApp.zip`
    }); and in my electron app in the error I have  System.Exception: Invalid release entry: {"url":"http://localhost:3000/releases/wind/1.0.4/MyApp.zip"}

Comment: Maybe you should specify protocol? Add at the start of the query `http://`.